# Understanding a PEM file and verifying the signature manually

Tags: certificates

I'm playing around with RSA for learning and understanding.

i got the following PEM file from the browser (BASE 64)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE/jCCA+agAwIBAgISBGzkPWVoI1CDdChcRxp7jO1hMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD
EwJSMzAeFw0yNDAyMTAwMzQ2MjFaFw0yNDA1MTAwMzQ2MjBaMBkxFzAVBgNVBAMT
Dmh0dHBzLWd1aWRlLmRlMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
p7jmFSTUYpTTIN/Qvvh9/cXNTvPY5+3sCLfxn+2DMQs+wi+tGX31n5Wk3G0GRg9q
XQ9awYaeIEjYWDpLHzwlWB5PNk1FhzO3ZYPgBDrQAqBI1TSPhQNmIm8WA5V5juQl
yEGI9efqZOuFm+1oIqFFbNtQ4ty/Vg6+FuJJx6KaRUmhQ6hpypuW4cz81ytVVJ0i
6E4rDE+jcQEHoRPxQ9K8/WkjCCuzUEdklGy9t+Jv4fUjlI2AKvhVOJKzBO8UjhTV
+tjCBR/PTmWq5Xi5NXmKx34/sgHNqx86DQ9xDiAv3X8jOiHK5eH5PhV1xKmp9BGq
OaQwG8JSDHsdt2qgy2xlnQIDAQABo4ICJTCCAiEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0G
A1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB0GA1Ud
DgQWBBRD3wUGbTVubIcA7UYVRBcRVP9XcDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQULrMXt1hWy65Q
CUDmH6+dixTCxjBVBggrBgEFBQcBAQRJMEcwIQYIKwYBBQUHMAGGFWh0dHA6Ly9y
My5vLmxlbmNyLm9yZzAiBggrBgEFBQcwAoYWaHR0cDovL3IzLmkubGVuY3Iub3Jn
LzAtBgNVHREEJjAkgg5odHRwcy1ndWlkZS5kZYISd3d3Lmh0dHBzLWd1aWRlLmRl
MBMGA1UdIAQMMAowCAYGZ4EMAQIBMIIBBQYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB9gSB8wDxAHcA
SLDja9qmRzQP5WoC+p0w6xxSActW3SyB2bu/qznYhHMAAAGNkVaAmwAABAMASDBG
AiEA+YNF9WpuxNwggP9a0qHI1TXZK6ykYazxSMZDgJAqV34CIQDl05SPwsN+uDBg
PKBbu3RtPCuzXVRvSDMvggQd/lUoyAB2AKLiv9Ye3i8vB6DWTm03p9xlQ7DGtS6i
2reK+Jpt9RfYAAABjZFWgQkAAAQDAEcwRQIhANkJGz5gIcPrQEMerOTz+Y/X7KLG
JIaHP5jKiJd+OIxYAiAB+KbOm64IxyM+T8Kyr4SRimc05QEiHEaUw1zuUud8dTAN
BgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAAhTC1jNPx0WEW65qYjotHJPUsGN/PxwdQnloPcPn
gI5sq/H1jCwxaaw2DpOdD8fwAfYKMdtgQG2oKTeIRjn/AvpdYUab7S1WkC61LpGw
6lEZH2dp8Krcy0xL8BcCUR+ET2x+Zb3UKjkafZNW9XCQuRi8f6tlpJ5BpEhcJCQ6
2eU5Y10BnBZk+KiSV1rocAUtVM3Gy1m0MB6tBXayCXhOoHBmOjw/z591+k8ahOzA
DNxW3uX9Tfak/15XRKRp+Je5YpKV/8ww+LX4tO4vCK72RaD4QSsb2LRORH6BoLZA
lDPil4lBDrB40ojuGV8KaMmq88Sf2bCSTYX1pt/5bOtOyw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
Subject Name
CN (Common Name):   https-guide.de
Issuer Name
C (Country):    US
O (Organization):   Let's Encrypt
CN (Common Name):   R3
Issued Certificate
Version:    3
Serial Number:  04 6C E4 3D 65 68 23 50 83 74 28 5C 47 1A 7B 8C ED 61
Not Valid Before:   2024-02-10
Not Valid After:    2024-05-10
Certificate Fingerprints
SHA1:   0D 0D 1A 18 7D 9A 59 8E 40 5C 71 3B CF 46 14 E3 6B 5E B5 05
MD5:    9A AC AA 7E 7D 51 22 0E F0 DB 89 C8 67 A4 67 DF
Public Key Info
Key Algorithm:  RSA
Key Parameters: 05 00
Key Size:   2048
Key SHA1 Fingerprint:   29 A8 72 98 2E 6E 88 D0 F8 AB 0C C7 65 D4 56 95 94 2E F9 2E
Public Key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
Key Usage
Usages: Digital signature Key encipherment
Critical:   Yes
Extended Key Usage
Allowed Purposes:   Server Authentication Client Authentication
Critical:   No
Basic Constraints
Certificate Authority:  No
Max Path Length:    Unlimited
Critical:   Yes
Subject Key Identifier
Key Identifier: 43 DF 05 06 6D 35 6E 6C 87 00 ED 46 15 44 17 11 54 FF 57 70
Critical:   No
Extension
Identifier: 2.5.29.35
Value:  30 16 80 14 14 2E B3 17 B7 58 56 CB AE 50 09 40 E6 1F AF 9D 8B 14 C2 C6
Critical:   No
Extension
Identifier: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1
Value:  30 47 30 21 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 30 01 86 15 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 72 33 2E 6F 2E 6C 65 6E 63 72 2E 6F 72 67 30 22 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 30 02 86 16 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 72 33 2E 69 2E 6C 65 6E 63 72 2E 6F 72 67 2F
Critical:   No
Subject Alternative Names
DNS:    https-guide.de
DNS:    www.https-guide.de
Critical:   No
Extension
Identifier: 2.5.29.32
Value:  30 0A 30 08 06 06 67 81 0C 01 02 01
Critical:   No
Extension
Identifier: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2
Value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
Critical:   No
Signature
Signature Algorithm:    1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
Signature Parameters:   05 00
Signature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
```

**1) How can i verify the signature manually?**
i know the Issuer is  "Let's Encrypt"
i got the public key of Let's Encrypt from the chain of PEM files

```
#PUBLIC KEY
exponent: 65537
modulo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
```

i tried to verify the signature manually with a short browser console Javascript

```
var modulo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
signature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
signature_decrypt;

modulo=BigInt("0x"+modulo.replace(new RegExp(":","g"),""));
signature=BigInt("0x"+signature.replace(new RegExp(" ","g"),""));

signature_decrypt=signature;
for (let i=0;i<16;i++)  //-- exponent: 65537 -> 2**16=65536
  {
  signature_decrypt=signature_decrypt**2n % modulo
  }

signature_decrypt=signature_decrypt*signature % modulo  //65537
console.log (signature_decrypt.toString(16));
```

i got the following output:

```
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
```

Because of the padding i got, i think this is the right decrypted signature, but i dont know from which part of the pem file i should build the sha256 hash value, because i got no equality - or my decryption is wrong
The complete pem file includes the signature, so i think the sha256 value should be made on the part before, but where exactly. can somebody help out?

**2nd question**: there are two certificate time stamps inside the pem SHA256

```
48:B0:E3:6B:DA:A6:47:34:0F:E5:6A:02:FA:9D:30:EB:1C:52:01:CB:56:DD:2C:81:D9:BB:BF:AB:39:D8:84:73
```

```
A2:E2:BF:D6:1E:DE:2F:2F:07:A0:D6:4E:6D:37:A7:DC:65:43:B0:C6:B5:2E:A2:DA:B7:8A:F8:9A:6D:F5:17:D8
```

who made that, and what are they about, why two? - can someboy link a page, where a pem file is explained line by line, because i searched for it and got only generally bla, bla, bla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I tried to verify the signature manually .... Because of the padding i got, i think this is the right decrypted signature, but i dont know from which part of the pem file i should build the sha256 hash value, because i got no equality - or my decryption is wrong.
>    The complete pem file includes the signature, so i think the sha256 value should be made on the part before, but where exactly.

You have it basically right, but need to be precise.

First, the PEM format is just a wrapper -- it represents some binary data as dash-BEGIN and dash-END lines surrounding base64 encoding with alphabet A-Za-z0-9+/ padding = and linebreaks. See [a good brief description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) or [the current standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468).

For a PEM-format *certificate*, the binary data is the [ASN.1 DER encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) of [a SEQUENCE of 3 elements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1):

1. the 'to-be-signed' (TBS) portion, also called the cert body or 'info', itself a fairly complicated sub-SEQUENCE;
2. an 'AlgorithmIdentifier' that identifies the signing algorithm (and is redundantly duplicated within the body), a SEQUENCE that starts with an OBJECT IDENTIFIER; and
3. a BIT STRING containing the signature value.

Thus the certificate data, obtained by base64-decoding the PEM body, consists of a header for the outer SEQUENCE; the encoded TBS; the encoded AlgorithmIdentifier; and the encoded BIT STRING. All of these are variable length, so in general you must look at the encodings to find out where each one begins and ends. The signature is computed over item 1 (the TBS) and for your example certificate it starts at byte offset 4 and has length 1002 bytes.

Coming from the other direction, the RSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature recovers (by modexp e) a 'representative' [which consists of](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2)

- one byte 01, as many bytes FF as fit given the key size = modulus size, and one byte 00
- the DER encoding of a DigestInfo SEQUENCE containing an AlgorithmIdentifier (similar to the one at the outer level, but here only for the hash not the full signature) plus an OCTET STRING containing the actual hash bytes.

Your recovered value minus the 01 FF... 00 padding is

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420bc56117d619d50579b700bd9e3fd275a2009234dbf413c89e13c0d12664188ff
```

which decodes as

```
3031 # tag-length for the outer SEQUENCE 
  300d # tag-length for the AlgId SEQUENCE
    0609608648016503040201 # OBJECT IDENTIFIER for SHA256
    0500 # NULL for parameters 
  0420 # tag-length for the OCTET STRING 
    bc56117d619d50579b700bd9e3fd275a2009234dbf413c89e13c0d12664188ff # actual bytes of hash
```

and sure enough if I take the bytes starting at 4 for 1002 from your data and compute SHA256, I get that hash.

Note the DigestInfo structure is simple enough that it can also be expressed as just a prefix depending only on the hash algorithm added to, and removed from, the hash value, as shown on the next page of the RFC8017 link I gave.

> 2. 2nd question: there are two certificate time stamps inside the pem SHA256
>    48:B0:E3:6B:DA:A6:47:34:0F:E5:6A:02:FA:9D:30:EB:1C:52:01:CB:56:DD:2C:81:D9:BB:BF:AB:39:D8:84:73
>    A2:E2:BF:D6:1E:DE:2F:2F:07:A0:D6:4E:6D:37:A7:DC:65:43:B0:C6:B5:2E:A2:DA:B7:8A:F8:9A:6D:F5:17:D8

Those aren't timestamps as such. See the more-informative decode using `openssl x509 -text`:

```
            CT Precertificate SCTs:
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 48:B0:E3:6B:DA:A6:47:34:0F:E5:6A:02:FA:9D:30:EB:
                                1C:52:01:CB:56:DD:2C:81:D9:BB:BF:AB:39:D8:84:73
                    Timestamp : Feb 10 04:46:21.851 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:46:02:21:00:F9:83:45:F5:6A:6E:C4:DC:20:80:FF:
                                5A:D2:A1:C8:D5:35:D9:2B:AC:A4:61:AC:F1:48:C6:43:
                                80:90:2A:57:7E:02:21:00:E5:D3:94:8F:C2:C3:7E:B8:
                                30:60:3C:A0:5B:BB:74:6D:3C:2B:B3:5D:54:6F:48:33:
                                2F:82:04:1D:FE:55:28:C8
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : A2:E2:BF:D6:1E:DE:2F:2F:07:A0:D6:4E:6D:37:A7:DC:
                                65:43:B0:C6:B5:2E:A2:DA:B7:8A:F8:9A:6D:F5:17:D8
                    Timestamp : Feb 10 04:46:21.961 2024 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:45:02:21:00:D9:09:1B:3E:60:21:C3:EB:40:43:1E:
                                AC:E4:F3:F9:8F:D7:EC:A2:C6:24:86:87:3F:98:CA:88:
                                97:7E:38:8C:58:02:20:01:F8:A6:CE:9B:AE:08:C7:23:
                                3E:4F:C2:B2:AF:84:91:8A:67:34:E5:01:22:1C:46:94:
                                C3:5C:EE:52:E7:7C:75
```

They are the logids for two SCTs. SCT is Signed Certificate Timestamp and is a structure *containing* a timestamp and a signature, generated by a log operator who committed the certificate information -- usually and in this case a so-called 'precertificate' -- immutably to a public trusted log, for the purpose of [Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency).

PS: you might also look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127095/manually-walking-through-the-signature-validation-of-a-certificate which details a similar process using openssl.

Comment: wow, thx! the best answers you get on unix stack exchange

Comment: lol, i tried ```echo -n "MIIE/jCCA+agAwI......pt/5bOtOyw==" | openssl base64 -d | dd bs=2 skip=4 iflag=skip_bytes count=1002```and wondered, why i get the wrong hash value. It took me half an hour to check that dd's count is not a byte count, ```dd bs=2 skip=4 iflag=skip_bytes count=501``` or ```dd bs=1 skip=4 iflag=skip_bytes count=1002```. THX!!! i now know  the start of the certificate```308204fe308203e6``` 30 is start of outer sequence, 82 is length with 7th Bit set to 1, which indicates that Bits 6-0 now indicate that the following two bytes are the length count.